# How can I plot box-plots for principal components 1, 2 and 3 for three different groups?

Tags: r, boxplot, pca

I have computed a principal component analysis (PCA) and derived a plot with PC1 vs PC2. This shows the variation in expression of around 14 genes when comparing three disease groups (  0 (control),  1 (ulcerative colitis) and 2 (Crohn's disease).

I would like to have a box plot for each group for the first three principal components, resulting in 9 Box and Whisker plots altogether.

The matrix of data prior to calculating the PCA has row names that correspond to the numbers 0,1 or 2. The columns represent different genes ( and the corresponding gene expression values).

I used prcomp to calculate the PCA plot (scaled and centered and also log-transformed).

Here is a snapshot of my matrix prior to PCA;

```
    structure(c(9.11655423831332, 10.489164314825, 1.91402056531454, 
    7.15827328042159, 4.24137583841638, 8.27769344002199, 8.56104058610663, 
    10.4808234419919, 2.90978833628418, 6.23818256006594, 5.22964773531333, 
    10.7708328724305, 7.29461400089235, 11.8318994425553, 3.03424662623575, 
    8.01272738639518, 4.99017087770597, 11.5985078491858, 7.81888257764922, 
    11.9022935347989, 1.27378277405718, 7.22371591364402, 5.35032777682152, 
    11.3245694322554, 7.53493825433311, 12.3702117577478, 2.28591365299837, 
    6.3684670711928, 4.79325114470697, 11.2368359301193, 7.42400102411584, 
    10.4893608659259, 2.29357094839174, 7.39880980207098, 4.06127337845416, 
    10.064874404576, 8.23639009062635, 12.041628287702, 1.68881444318413, 
    6.83433748681479, 4.58216981866268, 10.7369117797388, 8.52022902181642, 
    11.8310518930764, 1.09698581801487, 7.01560705946119, 4.42096319700341, 
    9.55024900954538, 6.78397242802669, 10.7346656491963, 1.8562428132184, 
    6.79381714159694, 4.76311785326908, 9.2896578696716, 7.38261637784709, 
   11.8956476271189, 0.676793904156995, 7.12068629785535, 4.50969591112091, 
   10.3965680730289, 7.76024460081224, 11.4191374294463, 2.51273901194187, 
    6.49764372886188, 5.95216200154652, 8.80877686581081, 7.92745512232284, 
    9.64936710370214, 2.75037060332872, 8.32919606967059, 5.13312284319216, 
    10.0205608136955, 8.32640003009823, 10.7914139100956, 3.07554840032925, 
    7.71871340592007, 5.75595649315905, 9.71791978048218, 7.13284940508783, 
   10.9113426747693, 1.07350504928193, 6.56249247218448, 5.35574874951741, 
   9.54833175767732), .Dim = c(6L, 14L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
   "1", "0", "0", "2", "2"), c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", 
   "Gene5", "Gene6", "Gene7", "Gene8", "Gene9", "Gene10", "Gene11", 
   "Gene12", "Gene13", "Gene14")))
```

Update; second question removed.

Code for PCA plot is as follows;

```
   data.mat.1.pca <- prcomp(log(data.mat.1), scale.=T, center=T)

   pcvalues <- summary(data.mat.1.pca)

   #colour coding each disease group

   rownames(data.mat.1)
   colour_disease <- rownames(data.mat.1)


   position_control<- grep("0", colour_disease)
   position_UC<- grep("1", colour_disease)
   position_Crohn<- grep("2", colour_disease)

   disease <- vector()
   disease[position_control] <- "lightskyblue"
   disease[position_UC] <- "lightslategrey"
   disease[position_Crohn] <- "lightpink2"



   ##proportion of variance explained for PC1 and PC2 for plot

   eigs<- data.mat.1.pca$sdev^2


  varExplained.pc1<- round(eigs[1]/sum(eigs), digits=3)*100

  varExplained.pc2 <- round(eigs[2]/sum(eigs), digits=3)*100


  plot(data.mat.1.pca$x[,1], data.mat.1.pca$x[,2],
   col=disease, bg=disease, pch=19, cex=1,
   xlab=paste("PCA 1 (", varExplained.pc1, "%)", sep=""),
   ylab=paste("PCA 2 (", varExplained.pc2, "%)", sep=""))
  legend("bottomright", legend = c("Control", "UC", "Crohns"),                

   fill=c("lightskyblue", "lightslategrey", "lightpink2"))
```

The values for the first three PCs are as follows;

```
                          PC1            PC2              PC3
  S.D                     3.6619        0.44801          0.30046
  Proportion of Variance  0.9578        0.01424          0.00645
  Cumulative proportion   0.9578        0.97215          0.97860
```

Here is a link to a research paper image https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Boxplots-of-the-first-three-principal-components-of-the-kidney-data-Group-specific_fig1_316641179

They are comparing control vs treatment, whilst I need three box plots (one for each group).

or this one https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Three-dimensional-principal-component-analysis-PCA-and-b-boxplots-of-principal_fig4_307533060

Comment: What groups are you talking about exactly? Can you show the code you used to do the PCA and make your current plot? And is the last paragraph asking a completely different question? You should ask just one clear question at a time.

Comment: For the first question. Add the PC scores for the first 3 components that you got from `prcomp` to your original data and you can plot any combination of boxplots you want. The second question is a bit vague, but you could start by comparing the principal components from the two analyses, PC1 with PC1, etc.

Comment: @MrFlick, please find updated code for PCA plot.  Ideally, I am trying to plot a box plot for control, UC and Crohn's for PC1, PC2 and PC3, so 9 box plots in total.

Comment: @dcarlson, please find attached the values for the first three components. If this was what you meant?

Comment: I was talking about the scores (e.g. `data.mat.1.pca$x[,1]`). You can create boxplots of these by group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite weird to plot the component scores like, but try the below to get a dot plot for the combinations you mentioned:

```
df = data.frame(disease=rownames(data.mat.1),data.mat.1.pca$x[,1:3])

df %>% pivot_longer(-disease) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=name,col=disease,y=value)) + 
geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge())
```

I hope you have more than 2 samples per group, unlike your example. Adding a boxplot is simply:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(-disease) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=name,col=disease,y=value)) + 
geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge())+
geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, extremely helpful.